# Send mail in C# without Password - Send failure error

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to implement a functionality in C# for mail sending, 
I **tried with gmail settings and it worked fine**.
but my requirement is to do it without password for mail id from which we r sending mail, my settings are

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("abcd@abcd.com", "pqrs@pqrs.com");

mailMessage.Subject = "Welcome";
mailMessage.Body = "---- Mail Body ---";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "000.000.000.000"; // we need to set a particular IP here
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "abcd@abcd.com";
NetworkCred.Password = "";
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Port = "25";
smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

It fires an error 'Failure Sending Mail'.
As per requirement we don't have password to the mail id, and SMTP port is an IP
First time facing this situation and googled a lot for this but can't find a solution

Please help

Comment: What is the response from the SMTP server?  If you have control over the server then it sounds like a problem with routing the mail under the conditions.  (Most SMTP servers don't allow unauthenticated sending by default.)  If you don't have control over the server then the "unauthenticated" requirement isn't under your control.

Comment: thanks @David - 'Unable to connect to the remote server' is the inner exception, and my IP 000.000.000.000:25 failed to connect

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot form one side to ask for enable SSL ( as it left from google settings)
and on the other not to send an email , also an Empty .string is still a value.
better remoteh property at all.
Try this

```
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailFrom"]);
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(email);
            string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpHost"];
            int port = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(host, port)
            {
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"])

            };
```

Ok updated it for something that works for sure - take into consideration that on this server we dont' care for a real password too - like your case , which means possible impersonation form the server.
Also a tip : I had a prob on a network with , the Active directovry restriction policy didn't allow locally to send the email , to avoid worm spreading

Comment: thanks @Dan Kuida - it doesn't work, here are some details,             System.Net.Mail.SMTPException - {"Failure sending mail."}

Inner Exception - {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

Status code - System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure

{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 000.000.000.000:25"} // IP is for an example can't disclose my IP